# why is my event listener not working on my buttons, i get an error

Tags: javascript, api, addeventlistener

I want to add an event listener to my buttons but it doesn't accept it. It says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener').

The tutorial I am following writes this code without buttons and I cant figure out how to add them. I need a little help here.

```js
const prev = document.querySelector('.prev');
const next = document.querySelector('.next');
const slideshow = document.querySelector('.slideshow');
var slideShow = document.getElementById("slideshow");
const data = fetch(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${breed}/images`);
let currentPosition = 0;

async function start() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all")
    const data = await response.json()
    createBreedList(data.message)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("There was a problem fetching the breed list.")
  }
}

start()

function createBreedList(breedList) {
  const dogBreed = document.getElementById("dogBreed");
  dogBreed.innerHTML = `
    <select onchange="loadByBreed(this.value)">
        <option>Choose a dog breed</option>
        ${Object.keys(breedList).map(function(breed) {
            return `<option>${breed}</option>`
        }).join('')}
    </select>`
}

async function loadByBreed(breed) {
  if (breed !== "Choose a dog breed") {
    const response = await fetch(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${breed}/images`)
    const data = await response.json()
    createSlideshow(data.message)
  }
}

function createSlideshow(images) {
  slideShow.innerHTML = `
    <button aria-label="Previous Photo" class="prev">←</button>
    <img src="${images[currentPosition]}" class="slide"></img>
    <button class="next" aria-label="Next Photo">→</button>`
}

function nextImage(e) {
  slideShow.innerHTML[currentPosition]
  currentPosition++
}

next.addEventListener('click', nextImage)
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Dog App</h1>
    <div id="dogBreed"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow" id="slideshow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You SELECT the buttons BEFORE you add them!!!! You are yelling for a guy in a room before he enters the room. He is not going to hear you. Reference and add the events when you ADD the buttons....

Comment: ```i did add them in the beginning of the code. Const next and prev

Comment: Yes it is at the beginning of the code. How can it FIND the elements before you add them? You add the two buttons to the page after you make the Ajax call to the server..... So you are dynamically creating the buttons and you try to FIND the buttons BEFORE you create them and add them to the document. The getElementById method does not keep looking for the elements. It only looks for it when you execute that line of code. 

 So you want to do `createSlideshow(data.message); prev = document.querySelector('.prev'); prev.addEventListener(....)`